# Migrating Azure Mobile Service to AppService and swapping apns certificate

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

Our team has migrated from Azure Mobile Service to AppService and all works fine, except now we need to swap the APNS cert as it's reaching its expiry date.

According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services it has to be done manually in the file system.

Can someone explain how to do it, using the legacy push? Is it the FTP that I need to use? or maybe something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I happily found an answer to this question and I thought it'd be good for others who don;t want to upgrade to NH to share it.

It's enough to go to App Service Editor -> App_Data and swap the certificate there. And this is really it. No need to go to Notification Hubs.

This isn't a Microsoft's recommened approach but it's safe for applications that are already in production state.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain how to do it, using the legacy push?

Currently, the Mobile Apps feature of Azure App Service uses Azure Notification Hubs to send pushes,so we need to configurate the notification for the Appservice. The following is the detail steps:

1.In the azure portal,go to your app service and click [push]

2.Click connect to connect or add a notification hub source to the app

3.Click [Configure push notification services] to configurate push notification 
services.

[image]

4.Upload the certificate

[image]

We also could get more info from the azure [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push).

Comment: This is ok when I'd like to go with recommended move to NotificationHubs and I just wanted to swap the cert that is used for Legacy Push. Just like in the article I mentioned.

Comment: Based on my understanding, you need to [export](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20122?locale=en_US) your certificate from your Mac and upload to  Push Notification Services. More details please refer to  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-and-run-the-ios-project-optional)

Comment: The document I Added reads-> that if I don;t want to upgrade it's enough to change it in the file system. And I don;t want to upgrate at the moment